# Websphere - Spring Integration SSL issue

Tags: spring, websphere, spring-integration, truststore

Our Spring Integration application runs on Websphere. It is a client to an SSL external service.

I've imported a certificate using Retrive from port [into default trust store], giving host and 443 port. Enabled tracing on WebSphere and it seems it is looking at cacert file and not trust.p12.

```
[18-2-19 13:44:59:154 CET] 00000063 SystemOut     O 2019-02-18 13:44:59.153  INFO 30426 --- [ver.startup : 0] pertySourcedRequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped URL path [/v2/api-docs] onto method [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<springfox.documentation.spring.web.json.Json> springfox.documentation.swagger2.web.Swagger2Controller.getDocumentation(java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)]
[18-2-19 13:44:59:826 CET] 00000063 SystemOut     O keyStore is: /srv/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/8.0/jre/lib/security/cacerts
```

**Code:**

```
public class PreemptiveMessageSender extends HttpComponentsMessageSender {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env; 

    private String host;
    private String userId;
    private String password;

    public PreemptiveMessageSender() {
        super();
    }

    public PreemptiveMessageSender(HttpClient httpClient) {
        super(httpClient);
    }

    @Override
    protected HttpContext createContext(URI uri) {

        HttpHost targetHost = new HttpHost(host, 443, "https");

        String decryptedPassword = getDecryptedPassword();

         CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
         credsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, 
                    new UsernamePasswordCredentials(userId, decryptedPassword));

         AuthCache authCache = new BasicAuthCache();
         authCache.put(targetHost, new BasicScheme());

         // Add AuthCache to the execution context
         final HttpClientContext context = HttpClientContext.create();
         context.setCredentialsProvider(credsProvider);
         context.setAuthCache(authCache);

         return context;        
    }

    private String getDecryptedPassword() {
        BasicTextEncryptor textEncrypt = new BasicTextEncryptor();

        textEncrypt.setPassword(env.getProperty("KEY_PASSWORD"));
        return textEncrypt.decrypt(password);       
    }

    @Override
    public WebServiceConnection createConnection(URI uri) throws IOException {

        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(uri);
        if (isAcceptGzipEncoding()) {
            httpPost.addHeader(HttpTransportConstants.HEADER_ACCEPT_ENCODING,
                    HttpTransportConstants.CONTENT_ENCODING_GZIP);
        }
        HttpContext httpContext = createContext(uri);
        return new CustomHttpComponentsConnection(getHttpClient(), httpPost, httpContext);
    }

    ... 
}
```

**Error**:

> "exception": "org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceIOException",
>       "message": "I/O error: com.ibm.jsse2.util.h: PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException:
>   PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.; internal
>   cause is: \n\tjava.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The
>   certificate issued by CN=ODC Test Root CA - G1, O=ODC Test, C=TU is
>   not trusted; internal cause is:
>   \n\tjava.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate
>   chaining error; nested exception is
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: com.ibm.jsse2.util.h: PKIX path
>   building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException:
>   PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.; internal
>   cause is: \n\tjava.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The
>   certificate issued by CN=ODC Test Root CA - G1, O=ODC Test, C=TU is
>   not trusted; internal cause is:
>   \n\tjava.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate
>   chaining error",

**Question**:
Is this problem with Spring Integration using the java cacert? How to make it use the trust store of WebSphere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll start with I don't know anything about Spring.  But given the behavior you talk about it must be creating its own instance of the SSLContext.   This will cause it to by pass WebSphere SSL settings.   It must be doing something like SSLContext.getInstance() to create its own instance or it could be doing something like SSLContext.getDefault() which returns you the JDK's default SSLContext.  Both will not get you a WebSphere SSLContext.

Comment: I can understand, but getDefault, though not tried yet, should get the WAS environment? Hope I will get an answer that works

Comment: Well no SSLContext.getDefault() will get you the JSSE's default SSLContext.  WebSphere does not do anything to reset the JSSE's default SSLContext.setDefault().  WebSphere uses a custom SSLSocketFactory, you can get it by calling SSLSocketFactory.getDefault().   With it you will get access to WebSphere's ssl configurations.

Comment: thanks for the pointers. Used HttpClients, HttpClientBuilder, blah blah and got errors Content-length header always present etc. But finally found a link that fixed. sorry, but adding as another answer

Comment: Aww,  there there is something else you should do in that case.   HttpClientBuilder has an option called useSystemProperties().   That will allow the Apache code to pick up the WebSphere configuration.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/394270/im-using-an-apache-httpclient-to-make-an-outbound/

> HttpClient theClient =
>   HttpClientBuilder.create().useSystemProperties().addInterceptorFirst(new
>   RemoveSoapHeadersInterceptor()).build();

```
private static class RemoveSoapHeadersInterceptor implements HttpRequestInterceptor {
        @Override
        public void process(HttpRequest request, HttpContext context) throws HttpException, IOException {
            if (request instanceof HttpEntityEnclosingRequest) {
                if (request.containsHeader(HTTP.TRANSFER_ENCODING)) {
                    request.removeHeaders(HTTP.TRANSFER_ENCODING);
                }
                if (request.containsHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_LEN)) {
                    request.removeHeaders(HTTP.CONTENT_LEN);
                }
            }
        }   
    }
```